# Draw and GeometryFunction (OL5 - Typescript)

Tags: openlayers, typescript

I'm trying to update my OL3 code (javascript) in OL5 (typescript) and I don't know how to fix this "GeometryFunction". Do you know how to build the GeometryFunction object?

```
var myDraw = new Draw({
  source: sourceVector,
  type: GeometryType.LINE_STRING,
  geometryFunction: myGeometryFunction,
  style: myStyle
});

var myGeometryFunction: GeometryFunction = function (coords: any[], geom: LineString) {
  if (!geom) {
    geom = new LineString([]);
  }
  geom.setCoordinates(coords);
  return geometry;
}
```

> Type '(coords: any[], geom: LineString) => LineString' is not assignable to type 'GeometryFunction'.

**EDIT**
I solved the compilation errors changing this part of the code, but I don't know if it is correct. Could this throws exceptions?

```
var myGeometryFunction: GeometryFunction = function (coords: any[], geom: SimpleGeometry | undefined) {
  if (!geom) {
    geom = new LineString([]);
  }
  geom.setCoordinates(coords);
  return <LineString>geom;
}
```

Comment: The GeometryFunction type definition is used for the geometry option of styles.

Comment: `geom.setCoordinates(geom)` will cause an OpenLayers error, it expects an array of coordinates.  You only need a geometry function if you want to produce a different geometry to what the interaction would produce by default for the clicked and current coordinates.

Comment: @Mike sorry, It was a mistake copying the code here.